# Using Streamlit and matplotlib to display a pandas dataframe bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, streamlit

At the moment I have:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True)
st.pyplot(fig)
```

The dataframe for reference if necessary looks like:

```
       A     B     C     D      E
Cat1  5.3   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
Cat2  NaN   NaN   12.1  NaN    NaN
Cat3  NaN   NaN   NaN   3.4    4.5
Cat4  NaN   2.8   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

where if I get rid of the `fig` in `st.pyplot(fig)`, forcing the function to render the global figure - it produces a nice stacked bar plot, but with the deprecation warning.

So I know it's not a problem with matplotlib producing the plot from my dataframe, but actually with streamlit displaying the plot.

Basically, what matplotlib syntax do I need to get streamlit to produce this horizontal stacked bar plot?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can remove fig from st.pyplot() and streamlit will show your plot.
Or you can render the horizontal bar plot with altair.

Internal streamlit chart builder (that is altair's wrapper) will also produce your plot, but not with horizontal bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st
st.set_option('deprecation.showPyplotGlobalUse', False)
st.set_page_config(page_title="Stacked Bar",layout="wide")
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df1=df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index')
chart=alt.Chart(df1).mark_bar().encode(
    y=alt.Y("index:N", title=""),
    x="value:Q",
    color="variable:N").properties(height=300)



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True)

col1, col2, col3 = st.columns(3)

with col1:
    st.title('Matplotlib plot')
    st.pyplot()

with col2:
    st.title('Altair plot')
    st.altair_chart(chart, use_container_width=True)

with col3:
    st.title('Streamlit plot')
    st.bar_chart(df)
```

[image: bar_h.png]